# Odd form closing behavior when using taskbar's Close All Windows

Tags: winforms

I have a Windows Forms app with a main window and 0 or more other windows open.  The other open windows are not owned by the main window nor are they modal dialogs or anything.  However, the default behavior is if the main window closes then the application closes due to the `Application.Run` method returning.  That's fine, but because the user may have unsaved work in the other opened windows I implemented some form closing logic.

When an other window is closed, it checks for unsaved changes and prompts the user with a standard Save/Don't save/Cancel Microsoft Word style prompt.

When the main window is closed, it attempts to first close all other open windows.  If any of them fail to close (i.e. user clicked Cancel), then it stops the closing event.

This logic occurs in the FormClosing events and works great except if the user uses the taskbar's "Close all windows" command.  This appears in 7's new taskbar as well as XP/Vista when grouping is active (though then it is labeled "Close Group").

This command seems to send a close message to all windows.  The problem is that each other window checks for changes and prompts and then the main window attempts to close other windows.  If I prompt the user using a standard MessageBox.Show command, then the closing event pauses while the dialog is waiting for a user response.  Once a button is clicked, it is processed as normal, but all other windows either discard or disregard the window close command.  It doesn't matter what they clicked, either.  The form showing the prompt reacts correctly (if they hit Cancel it remains open, if not, it closes normally).  But all other windows including the main act like nothing happened.  Their FormClosing event is never raised.

If I use a TaskDialog (via calling unmanaged [TaskDialogIndirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760544%28VS.85%29.aspx)), then at the point when the prompt should appear and pause the form closing event, instead the other forms process their form closing events.  This is on the same thread no less (the main UI thread).  When the main window's turn comes around, it attempts to close all forms like normal.  Any form that attempted to prompt is still open, the rest have since closed on their own due to the "Close all windows" command.  The main window attempts to close those still remaining, resulting in a second FormClosing event to process and a second attempt to prompt (after all, the changes are still unsaved!) all on the main thread mind you.

The end result is that the prompt then appears twice in succession after unwinding through the call stack.  I know this is all happening on the same thread via Visual Studio's call stack.  I can look back all the way at any point to the first prompt attempt up to the time when it is about to call it again.  Only the second call seems to actually process it and show the prompt.  The first time through it is almost like somewhere in the unmanaged code it is yielding to other messages.  I should mention up front that I do not call Application.DoEvents anywhere myself.

Is TaskDialogIndirect some kind of semi-asynchronous call?  But I never leave the main thread through all of this so far as I can tell.  And then why does the standard MessageBox prompt immediately (as I would think TaskDialog should too), but then appear to drop all the other window close events?  Are the other window close messages just timing out maybe?  Shouldn't they just be pending in the message queue until the modal dialog (the message box) returns?

I have a feeling this is all due to the "managed wrapper for Win32 API" nature of Windows Forms — a [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Close all windows (since XP) implementation is kind of hacky. In your `FormClosing` implementation check if the form is disabled because a `TaskDialog` or any other prompt is shown with the form being the owner of the prompt.

While you're at it check how your closing scheme performs upon [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890(VS.85).aspx) i.e. user logs off with changes pending.

Comment: I have proper checks that should a Shutdown or Task Manager force quit occur that it skips these checks for changes and just discards them.  The Close-all-windows command appears as a standard UserClosing cause, just as if they clicked the red X.  I cannot check for open TaskDialogs as they have not appeared yet.  The first time I attempt to show one, it seems to yield to the other form closing events before actually appearing itself.

Comment: Check your form for WS_DISABLED before showing the save changes prompt. Start a Notepad and type anything then try to log off and you get a confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The `Close all windows` sends the `WM_CLOSE` to all windows in the taskbar group, which usually(always?) includes the main window. Many applications have a confirm dialog prompt on the main window, but not on child windows. Some child windows may receive the `WM_CLOSE` message before the main window and thus will be closed even if the user decides to cancel the close request.

Here is some code that intercepts the `WM_CLOSE` messages and then `posts` the `WM_CLOSE` to the main window if it was one of the windows that was sent the message. This prevents the child windows from closing, which is nice if the user decides to cancel the close request.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {

public static class CloseAllWindowsHandler {

    private const int WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
    private const int WM_DESTROY = 0x2;

    static List<NW> closing = new List<NW>();
    static List<NW> nws = new List<NW>();
    static Thread thread = null;
    static IntPtr hwndMainWindow = IntPtr.Zero;

    private class NW : NativeWindow {

        // determine to allow or deny the WM_CLOSE messages
        bool intercept = true;

        public NW() {}

        protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) {
            if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE) {
                if (!intercept) {
                    intercept = true;
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    return;
                }

                closing.Add(this);

                Thread t = null;
                t = new Thread(() => {
                    try {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    } catch {}

                    if (thread == t) {
                        // no more close requests received in the last 100 ms
                        // if a close request was sent to the main window, then only post a message to it
                        // otherwise send a close request to each root node at the top of the owner chain
                        NW nwMain = null;
                        foreach (NW nw in closing) {
                            if (nw.Handle == hwndMainWindow) {
                                nwMain = nw;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
                        var closing2 = closing;
                        closing = new List<NW>();
                        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) => {
                            try {
                                if (nwMain != null) {
                                    // if the 'Close all windows' taskbar menu item is clicked, then closing2.Count
                                    // will contain all the window handles
                                    nwMain.intercept = false;
                                    PostMessage(hwndMainWindow, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                                }
                                else {
                                    // doesn't seem to ever happen, closing2.Count always equals 1
                                    // so nothing really has to be done
                                    // if (closing2.Count > 1)

                                    foreach (NW nw in closing2) {
                                        nw.intercept = false;
                                        PostMessage(nw.Handle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                                    }
                                }
                                bgw.Dispose();
                            } catch {}
                        };
                        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
                    }
                });
                thread = t;
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                t.Start();
                return;
            }
            else if (m.Msg == WM_DESTROY) {
                ReleaseHandle();
                nws.Remove(this);
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

    private static void RegisterWindow(IntPtr hwnd) {
        NW nw = new NW();
        nws.Add(nw); // prevent garbage collection
        nw.AssignHandle(hwnd);
    }

    private const int WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
    private const int EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE = 0x8000;

    public static void AssignHook(IntPtr mainWindowHandle) {
        hwndMainWindow = mainWindowHandle;
        uint pid = 0;
        uint tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(mainWindowHandle, out pid);
        CallWinEventProc = new WinEventProc(EventCallback);
        hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, IntPtr.Zero, CallWinEventProc, pid, tid, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);      
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventProc lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

    private static IntPtr hHook = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static WinEventProc CallWinEventProc;
    private delegate void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime);
    private static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, int iEvent, IntPtr hWnd, int idObject, int idChild, int dwEventThread, int dwmsEventTime) {
        if (iEvent == EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE) {    
            IntPtr pWnd = GetParent(hWnd);
            if (pWnd == IntPtr.Zero) { // top level window
                RegisterWindow(hWnd);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form {

    public Button btnOpen = new Button { Text = "Open" };
    public CheckBox cbConfirmClose = new CheckBox { Text = "Confirm Close" };
    private static int counter = 0;
    public Form2() {
        Text = "Form" + counter++;
        FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        panel.Controls.AddRange(new Control [] { btnOpen, cbConfirmClose });
        Controls.Add(panel);

        btnOpen.Click += btnOpen_Click;
    }

    void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Owner = this;
        f.Size = new Size(300,300);
        f.Show();
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (cbConfirmClose.Checked) {
            var dr = MessageBox.Show(this, "Confirm close?", "Close " + Text, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            if (dr != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }

        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}

public class Program2 {

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.HandleCreated += delegate {
            CloseAllWindowsHandler.AssignHook(f2.Handle);
        };
        Application.Run(f2);
    }
}

}
```